# Swift 3 unwrap and compare int in if

Tags: swift, if-statement, swift3, compare, option-type

I'm trying to unwrap a value and, if it works, compare it to be greater than 0.

I'm doing the following way:

```
if let movieLength = movie.length as? Int, movieLength > 0 {
    self.durationLabel.text = "\(movieLength) min"
} else {
    self.durationLabel.isHidden = true
}
```

But I get the error

> Downcast from 'Int?' to 'Int' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?

Also tried using the `where` keyword but no success:

```
if let movieLength = movie.length as? Int where movieLength > 0 {
    self.durationLabel.text = "\(movieLength) min"
} else {
    self.durationLabel.isHidden = true
}
```

with the error:

> Expected ',' joining parts of a multi-clause condition

Which I just tried above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need to explicitly unwrap in `if let`, just this should work

```
if let movieLength = movie.length, movieLength > 0 {
    self.durationLabel.text = "\(movieLength) min"
} else {
    self.durationLabel.isHidden = true
}
```

You can check the "Optional Binding" in [The Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) for right syntax.

Comment: That was dumb from me... I tried `if let movieLength = movie.length where movieLength > 0` but not with a comma in place of where. Thanks!